# How to write large numbers to a file without process not being frozen or killed by OS?

Tags: c++, linux, file, process

In a C++ program (Linux), I need to write some numbers (integers, one number per line) to a file, and the size may be very large (currently 25GB).

The numbers are 1 , -1 or 0, which are used to record the connections of node and arc in a large graph.

all the output is written to a file (.txt) by std::ofstream << ...

The printing code architecture is :

```
for  loop1 (node size)
    for  loop2  (arc size)
        filename << .......
```

If the output size is small, it works well.

But, when the output size is large, the shell terminal where the programming is running is frozen.

But the process is still running and after long time (hours) it is killed by OS.

No errors, warnings, segmentation faluts pop up.

What are the possible reasons ?

I tried to search it online, but do not find what I need.

Thanks

This is the output of  ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 399360
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 399360
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

in top command: 
It used < 200 MB .

Comment: Do you have a `ulimit` set for maximum file size?

Comment: posting real code might be helpful too (i.e. are you buffering?) Also there should be something in the syslog explaining the reason kernel decided to terminate the process.  Check /var/log/messages

Comment: Ever consider delineating your file?

Comment: I got "/var/log/messages" [Permission Denied]. Are there other ways to check log file or core dump ?

Comment: There _has_ to be a failed system / library call that returns an error to give you an indication. Are you checking all return values? We can't tell much without code!

Comment: The whole program is very large. it works well when the output file size is small.

Comment: How to check all return values ? The shell terminal is frozen and no response, I have to use ctrl-c to stop it.

Comment: In your code when you call functions such as `write`, or any library function that you didn't write, do you check the error code?

Comment: see if your sysadmin can look at the log file.  Also, are you outputting anything to the terminal by any chance?  Dumping too much to stdout can certainly cause your program to hang.

Comment: @MK, all the output is written to a file (.txt) by std::ofstream << ...

Comment: @skjaidev, all the output is written to a file (.txt) by std::ofstream << ..., what kinds of lib functions I have called potentially ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your program has a memory leak (you said your program was large and complex), which would continually request more memory from the OS as your program runs. This could explain why your machine becomes unresponsive (due to memory pressure load), and also could explain why the OS terminates your program when it runs out of memory to give you.

Try watching your program run with `top` or something. If the resident size increases without bound, this may be your problem. With a smaller data set, you probably wouldn't notice the problem.